# Why is the "o" pronounced differently in "Porto" and "portas"

Tags: pronúncia

The name **Porto** is pronounced `/'portʊ/` (closed o), but **portas** is pronounced `/'pɔrtɐʃ/` (open o). Why? Is there any specific rule for this behavior?

Comment: Are you looking for the difference between "porto" and "porta", or between "porto" and "portos"? Or both?

Comment: @DanGetz I think that he is not asking for neither, just asking what is the rule that says when the o is closed or open. A similar question might be done in English as "order" has an open o, but "post" has a closed one.

Comment: É bastante comum ocorrer essa abertura da vogal no plural, mas não sei as regras precisas.

Comment: http://www.seer.ufrgs.br/contingentia/article/view/11419/6766

Comment: @bfavaretto unfortunately, my Portuguese is not good enough to understand this article.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems your question has been discussed by experts in the language several times... The issue here is the "vogal aberta" (open vowel) vs the "vogal fechada" (closed vowel).

The answer is, to put it simply and bluntly: there is no consistent rule for the **o** in "Porto" to be closed and "porta" to be open, they are pronounced the way they are because the sound stuck like that throughout the centuries.

In the [link provided by bfavaretto](http://www.seer.ufrgs.br/contingentia/article/view/11419/6766), the relevant part is:

> Because it is an unmarked phenomenon, the use of [umlauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut_%28linguistics%29) become
>   **extremely difficult for students that have never before had contact with the Portuguese language**.
>
> ...
>
> There are cases like *forno*, in Latin [i.l.] *furnǔm*, *miolo* i.l.
>   *pǔteum*, *miolo* i.l. *medǔllum*, *formoso* i.l *formosum*, where (ǔ) and (ō) in Latin are open in the feminine and in the plural by
>   analogy, that is, by a linguistic change process consisting in
>   changing [morphs](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/morph) in order to fit an existing model. In these
>   cases, there is an open vowel antietimologicamente [I presume this
>   word means antimorphologically] that meets the singular masculine
>   scheme with a closed **o** and the plural masculine and the feminine
>   and masculine singular and plural with an open **o**, such as in
>   *fornos*, *poços*, *poças*, *miolos*, *gostosa* and *gostosos*.
>
> There are instances where the formation of the feminine and plural
>   remains **faithful to the etymology** and, therefore, does not adhere
>   to the analogy process. Such an occurrence is perceptible in words
>   like *lobo* [wolf] i.l. *lǔpum*, *gosto* [to like] i.l. *gǔstum*,
>   *esposo* [groom] i.l. *spōnsum*, which in the respective feminine and plural remain with a closed **o**, i.e. *lobas*, *lobos*, *gostos*,
>   *esposa*, *esposos*.

The important part to retain in this is *Porto* has the closed **o** due to being faithful to its etymology.

Therefore *Porto* is kind of the rule breaker because in the old times people used a closed **o** when pronouncing it... And you can tell this because, *portos* has an open vowel (unlike *lobos*) which is consistent even with the English word *ports* and *port* (both with an open vowel).

Furthermore, in [ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/origem-das-vogais-abertas-e-fechadas/4970) they explain the following:

> The list of plurals with an open **o** (as in *almoços* and *poços*)
>   will always increase, and there are always a few words whose plural
>   oscillates between **ô** [P**o**rto sound] and **ó** [P**o**rta
>   sound], until it ends, analogously, with the open vowel being imposed.
>   The list made by of our biggest phonetician, Gonçalves Viana, is already much
>   smaller than the current one, and in the life of a person, there are
>   numerous cases where changes like these happen.
>
> And there are errors, of course, by pseudo-scholasticism. So *molho*
>   (in cooking) keeps a closed **o** in the plural, but some careless
>   people "open" it, because they refer to a specific sauce (green
>   vegetable sauce) and its plural, both getting the open **o** (i.e.
>   *mɔlho* and *mɔlhos*).
>
> This [issue] would give a treaty; so sorry for not dwelling into more
>   details.

The conclusion is that, old closed vowels are prone to become open vowels.

So probably someday someone will say "É o *Pórto*!" and people around listening will flinch and some will say, "Não! Diz-se *Pôrto* carago!!!", but at the end of the day, they knew exactly what you were referring to (and they won't give a flying *carago* about it;).

Comment: So we should expect *novo* to someday change its first vowel so that it works like the first vowel in each of *novos, nova, novas* already works?  That is, we’ll someday say *nóvo* instead of *nôvo* the way one says *nóvos* instead of *nôvos*?

Comment: @tchrist these changes may take centuries, and they may still not be triggered if there isn't some kind of justification behind them (as the _molho_ example). But, for your specific case, it's curious that the [_nuovo_](https://translate.google.com/#it/pt/nuovo) in Italian has an open **o** (click the speaker button).